# MongoDB count distinct value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here below show my code. I have to calculate the how many times distinct value repeated. Here i have store distinct value in "results".I used collection.count() to calculate but it's not work. please any one tell me where i have to mistake. Thank you very much .

```
var DistinctIntoSingleDB = function(Collection,arr,opt,distVal,callback){
 Collection.find({}).distinct(distVal, function(err, results) {
      if(!err && results){
            console.log("Distinct Row Length :", results.length);
            var a,arr1 = [];
            for(var j=0; j<results.length; j++){
                collection.count({'V6': results[j]}, function(err, count) {
                      console.log(count)
                });

                arr1.push(results[j]+ " : " +a);
            }
            callback(results,arr1);
      }else{
           console.log(err, results);
           callback(results);
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get occurrences of distinct values of a field 'field1' on a collection 'col1' and write to a separate collection 'distinctCount'. Also allow to use disk space in case the collection is huge.

```
db.col1.aggregate(
          [{$group: {
              _id: "$field1",
              count: { $sum : 1 }
            }}, {
            $group: {
              _id: "$_id",
              count: { $sum : "$count" }
            }},{
              $out: "distinctCount"
            }],
         {allowDiskUse:true}
)
```

Comment: The second `$group` is not actually doing anything here since it's just using the same `_id` value, as well as passing through the same output value to `$sum`. Also `$out` was introduced in the same version where the default `.aggregate()` output is actually a "cursor", so previous problems with a result in a single BSON document are no longer a problem here. Other API's than the shell might "default" to a BSON document, but they can easily be altered to return a "cursor" instead. You only need to use `$out` where you actually "intend" to create a new collection for the results.

Answer (score 9):

While `.distinct()` works well for just obtaining the distinct values for a field, in order to actually get the counts of occurrences, this is better suited to the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/):

```js
Collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$field",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
],function(err,result) {

});
```

Also the `.distinct()` method does "abstract" from where the specified "distinct" field is actually within an array. In this case you need to call [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) first to process the array elements here:

```js
Collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$array" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$array.field",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
],function(err,result) {

});
```

So the main work is basically done in the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) by "grouping" on the field values, which means the same thing as "distinct". The [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) is a grouping operator which in  this case just adds up `1` for each occurrence of that value in the field for that collection.